# Kernel or Bezier curve smoothing for Kaplan-Meier Survival Estimate

Tags: bezier, spline, survival-analysis, smoothing

I am a civil engineering grad student working on survival modeling of bridges. I am using SAS with Kaplan-Meier method to analyze the data. I would like to overlay the survival probability plot with a smooth curve using either Kernel smoothing or Bezier smoothing. But since these methods are not available in statistic packages, I exported the survival probability to an excel in order to produce it manually (I may be wrong on doing this). After several attempt I could not figure out on how to do it in Excel.

I am attaching an excel file image with data and the Kaplan Meier curve I am working and would be grateful if someone could help me by coding either the kernel smoothing or Bezier smoothing steps and overlay the curve and repost the file here to me. Or, more effeciently provide me with an excel add in to do this or a SAS code to do this.

[image]

Comment: Is there some reason why you want to use this type of smoothing instead of a smooth curve produced by a parametric model (e.g., [LIFEREG in SAS](https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/stat/142/introsurv.pdf))? If a parametric model is appropriate the estimated parameter values would further provide additional information of interest.

Comment: The data I have does not fit any type of parametric models used for survival analysis. This is why I use Kaplan-meier method, and would like to provide a smooth curve along with the step curve due to a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If a parametric model providing a smoothed description of the survival data isn't appropriate, you could use smoothing splines or loess curves, compared on [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20032/28500) for example. For smoothing, multiple [Bézier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) are combined to form one type of spline, and loess is one form of a [kernel smoother](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_smoother). These are easily implemented in standard statistical software packages; for example, in SAS [TRANSREG](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/faq/how-can-i-use-proc-transreg-to-generate-splines-in-sas/) provides splines and [LOESS](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#loess_toc.htm) implements that locally-weighted regression.*

That said, baseline survival curves in clinical studies are typically presented as the type of step function that you display, without smoothing. Also, it seems that your underlying data might only provide information at 1-year intervals. If so, then presenting a smooth curve might be somewhat misrepresenting the smoothness of your data. If you do have individual event and censoring times for each bridge, then your smoothed curve should be based on the survival probabilities at each event time to provide the closest representation of your data.

---

*I would be wary of using Excel for any serious statistical work. I have found it too easy to make unforced errors that avoid detection in Excel.